# Update a numpy array except i-th entry

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement SGD algorithm, where there is a update formula 
[image]

This could be easily done by using

```
temp = beta_old[i]
beta = beta_old
beta[i] = temp
```

But I find this ugly and I am wondering if there is any more elegant way to do this (maybe by using some indexing tricks).

Comment: beta, beta_old[i] = beta_old[i], beta

Comment: @ThomasLang it's not two values, it's all values, except one. This doesn't work.

Comment: OP, neither the formula nor the snippet you posted make sense! Please revise the question.

Comment: @roganjosh 1) `i` is not used in the formula. 2) the code snippet is equivalent to `beta = beta_old`, there's no swapping going on.

Comment: ... @John I'm voting to close as unclear. You're right, the code is a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a mask:

```
mask = np.ones(size, dtype=np.bool)
mask[i] = false
```

Then use the mask later:

```
beta[mask] = beta_old[mask]
```

But it may be slower than your current method.